# Track access to database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I see who has accessed the database, viewed the tables or executed `SELECT`, for SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: What edition are you using?

Comment: If your focus is on who (and not just that a table or database has been accessed), I'd suggest placing more emphasis on that in both the body and the title. Perhaps I was the only one who missed the mark, but it can never hurt to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you're looking for is an **audit**.  You can achieve this through the use of *SQL Server Audit*.  With this tool, you will be able to audit Server and Database level actions and access.

To find out more information about how to use this tailored to your implementation, take a look at this BOL reference on [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280386%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This is available in Enterprise and Datacenter editions.

Comment: Gracias, I'll check this out. I see it can track SELECT, which is very important to me